# Project unique build number in teamcity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-10

Does anyone know if it is possible to have a build number which is unique to projects in TeamCity.

I know there is build.number which is sequential and unique per build configuration.

There is also teamcity.build.id which seems to be sequential and unique to the whole of TeamCity.

The reason I want a number per project is for packaging and archiving purposes.
Want to be able to package and store as ProjectName/BuildNumber but can't do this if multiple build configurations on the same project produce the same build numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, indeed. You'll need to use the [autoincrementer plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Autoincrementer).

Though the plugin page doesn't say so, it is compatible with TC10 (which I think is the version you're interested in, based on the question tag).